# JqGrid problem with striping and frozen columns

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I load the grid with striping and frozen columns. Loads correctly. The first line is white, the second line is gray.
When executing the sort on one of the columns, the frozen side starts in gray and the other side starts in white.

Version 4.15.6-free
How to adjust the colors?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UOD9.jpg)

```
    

    
    


     

    
    
    

    
    .myAltRowClass {
    background: #E0E0E0;
    }
    

    
    jqTreeGrid - Test zebra

     

    listaData=[
    {"termId":51843,"module":"M","option":"W","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["D","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52192,"module":"M","option":"P","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52338,"module":"B","option":"P","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52339,"module":"B","option":"","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52341,"module":"B","option":"S","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52342,"module":"B","option":"P","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52343,"module":"B","option":"D","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52344,"module":"B","option":"D","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52345,"module":"B","option":"","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxxs","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52346,"module":"B","option":"P","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52347,"module":"B","option":"P","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52348,"module":"B","option":"","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52349,"module":"B","option":"P","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52340,"module":"B","option":"","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["","","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":51848,"module":"B","option":"B","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"1","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["B","B","x","y","z","w"],"languagesTips":["B","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":51841,"module":"B","option":"S","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"1.01","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["P","S","","","",""],"languagesTips":["P","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":51842,"module":"B","option":"A","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"1.01.01","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["S","A","","","",""],"languagesTips":["U","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":52011,"module":"B","option":"U","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"1.01.01.01","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["U","U","","","",""],"languagesTips":["","","","","",""]},
    {"termId":51844,"module":"B","option":"P","termDescription":"xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx","termWidth":"0","orderGrid":"0","menuStructure":"1.01.01.02","quantityFrozenFields":0,"languagesTerms":["P","Ps","","","",""],"languagesTips":["P","","","","",""]}];


    var colModel = [{ label:'Module', name: 'module',    width: 160, frozen: true},
    { label:'Option', name: 'option',    width: 160, frozen: true},
    { label:'Description', name: 'termDescription',    width: 160, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal !important;"' }, frozen: true},
    { label:'Strucuture', name: 'menuStructure',    width: 80},
    { label: 'termId', name: 'termId', width: 10, hidden: true },
    { label:'Pt', name: 'languagesTerms.0', width:100, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal !important;"' }, editable: false},
    { label:'Pt', name: 'languagesTips.0', width:150, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal !important;"' }, editable: false, hidden: true},
    { label:'En', name: 'languagesTerms.1', width:100, editable: false},
    { label:'En', name: 'languagesTips.1', width:150, editable: false, hidden: true},
    { label:'Tu', name: 'languagesTerms.2', width:100, editable: false},
    { label:'Tu', name: 'languagesTips.2', width:150, editable: false, hidden: true},
    { label:'Cn', name: 'languagesTerms.3', width:100, editable: false},
    { label:'Cn', name: 'languagesTips.3', width:150, editable: false, hidden: true},
    { label:'Al', name: 'languagesTerms.4', width:100, editable: false},
    { label:'Al', name: 'languagesTips.4', width:150, editable: false, hidden: true},
    { label:'Ce', name: 'languagesTerms.5', width:100, editable: false},
    { label:'Ce', name: 'languagesTips.5', width:150, editable: false, hidden: true}];



    var lastSelection ;


    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery('#jqGrid').jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: listaData,
            height: 300,
            width : 900,

            colModel:colModel,


            loadonce: true,
            shrinkToFit: false, 
                rowNum: 500,
                scroll: 0,

                multiSort: false,

                   loadComplete: function() {
                        $("tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass('myAltRowClass');

                    }
        });    

        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");    
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to read the docs and search this forum. This functionality is build in in jqGrid (hope in free-jqGrid it is not depreciated).You will need just to use the grid option **altRows** and use option **altclass** to use your own class.

You problem is in using two features at the same time - loadComplete and FrozenColumns.

Comment: I understood.
I have adjusted the code and it is working correctly.
Thank you